# iOS MapBox - get annotation title in imageForAnnotation method

Tags: ios, mapbox

In the following method:

```
- (MGLAnnotationImage *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView imageForAnnotation:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation{
```

used to display a custom annotation UIImage, I would like to be able to differentiate my annotations (I can have 3 different types).

Ideally, I would like to be able to have a `tag` on the MGLAnnotation to easily identify what type of annotation it is, but I can also use a combination of the title, latitude and longitude to do so.

But in the method, I am unable to get the `annotation.coordinate`, or `annotation.title`.

How come? Can I make this properties accessible?

Comment: Did you finally find a nice way of identifying your annotations?

Comment: I subclassed my MGLAnnotation to have my own custom one and then simply added everything I wanted on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the coordinate and title of the annotation like this:

```
NSString *title = [annotation title];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [annotation coordinate];
```